# How to check if a SimpleHTMLDom element does not exist

Tags: php, if-statement, simple-html-dom

SimpleHtmldom can be used to extract the contents of the first element with class `description`.

```
$html = str_get_html($html);
$html->find('.description', 0)
```

However if this class does not exist, PHP will throw an error

`Trying to get property of non-object`

I tried

```
if(!isset($html->find('.description', 0))) {
    echo 'not set';
}
```

and

```
if(!empty($html->find('.description', 0))) {
    echo 'not set';
}
```

but both gives the error

```
Can't use method return value in write context
```

**What is the proper way to check if the element exist?**

Comment: `empty` cannot operat directly on the value. `$html->find()` returns an empty array if element was not found. So the solution offered by Death should be valid.

Comment: FYI: http://blog.futtta.be/2012/05/31/simple-html-dom-parser-not-that-simple/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if(($html->find('.description', 0))) {
    echo 'set';
}else{
    echo 'not set';
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: not work
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Comment: @AnassElFakir   `*_get_html` functions may return `false` :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SimpleHtmlDOM Api](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm) str_get_html($html) expects a string as input. First check with a html validator if your code is well formatted.

```
$htmlObj = str_get_html($html);
if (!is_object($htmlObj)) return; // catch errors 

// or wrap further code in 
if (is_object($htmlObj)) { /* doWork */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$avalable = ($element->find('span.sold-out-text', 0)) ? 1 : 0;
```

It **works** for me.