# Simple HTML Dom: check if tag exist

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to check if there is and image after the  tag, and if there is grab the width value. the method i'm using below is not working

```
$element = $html->find("td", 23);
if ($element->innertext != null) {
    $element = $html->find("td img[src=http://pictures.domain.com/images/7.gif]");
    echo $element->width . '<br />';        
} else {
   echo "empty";
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with simpleHtmlDOM, but try quoting the `src` attribute: `$html->find('td img[src="http://pictures.domain.com/images/7.gif"]');`

Comment: Which part is not working? Does the IF work fine? the first find() i mean?

Comment: FYI: http://blog.futtta.be/2012/05/31/simple-html-dom-parser-not-that-simple/

Comment: Another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12071267/216084

Answer (score 3):

I got around this problem by using `is_object()` and `is_array()`.

When you search for a single element, an object is returned. When you search for a set of elements, an array of objects is returned.

`$td = $html->find("td", 23)` is searching for a single element, so using the following will check for the existence of the searched-for element:

```
$td = $html->find("td", 23);
if (is_object($td)) {
    //continue
}
```