# How to detect element is exist or not

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Hello everyone i am fetching data by using simple html dom

This is my code of php which is fetching data from site
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($this->main_url.$lin->link);
if($html){
    //check if language heading h2 exist then process forward
    if($html->find('h2.channel-title',0)){
        fetch data from tables
     }
}
```

This line `if($html->find('h2.channel-title',0))` finding h2.channel-title in find function of simple html dom give me a fatal error when h2.channer-title is not exist

In many pages `<h2 class="channel-title"> English Links</h2>` exists so i have code according to them and process further in my foreach loop it's working fine and fetched all data.

**But**

when `<h2 class="channel-title">English Links</h2>` tag is not exist it give me an **error**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\autobot\engine\simple_html_dom.php on line 1113
```

Please help me i am stuck in it need help thank you. i want if h2.channel-title exist run my foreach code else run another but don't give an error its stop my whole script. :(

Comment: That's not really happening, there's something else wrong with your code but I can't tell what it is. Try to simplify.

Comment: bro and above code is not completed i give only example or some part of code which give me error

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a SimpleHTMLDom element does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071213/how-to-check-if-a-simplehtmldom-element-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($this->main_url.$lin->link);

if($html) {
    $var = $html->find('h2.channel-title',0);

    if(isset($var)) {
        fetch data from tables
    } else{
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: is this the same that: if($html->find('h2.channel-title',0)) {} ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($html);
```

Which library you are using?

Comment: simple html dom and i have dump but in some pages there is h2 element and in some pages there is no element so how can i detect it?

Comment: I think $html is no object, so the method "find" can't be called. Sure that the reason is that are no h2.channel-title in the page. Possible Parse error?

Comment: guys please help me how can i do that please thank you